# How can I close my browser pop-up Ads? (can't be blocked)

Tags: malware, web-browser

How can I close my browser pop-up ads?

When I use my browser. There's ads everywhere, even in the google main page.

I can't seem to close ads how many time I click close.

When I tried to block the ads with not allowing pop-up, I found that the setting is blocked (greyed).

What should I do?

Edit: Strangely only one user that affected. When I used another user it doesn't likely to happen even on the same browser.

Comment: it looks like your browser is infected- remove completely and reinstall

Comment: May be the browser is okay with Adblocker installed. Adblock never blocks 100% popups.

Comment: @Vaibs there are no pop-ups on Google's main page - the OP is infected with adware

Comment: Right! It may be adware. non verified plugins/extensions. Reinstalling will always work :)

Comment: @Vaibs no, reinstalling will not always work. this isn't 1996. Malware authors have become *slightly* smarter.

Comment: If we clear all the working locations of the browsers ? APPDATA content ..?

Comment: Nope. Nope. Nope. Often, you'll find such software has in fact infected the OS in a way that makes sure it gets installed as soon as a browser without it appears.

Comment: See if you have got a Proxy-Server installed (it injects ADDS and other unwanted stuff everyware, even if you are not using your browser) - if so try to remove it - reboot and see if it is back (the smart ones just wont go avay) ! If its gone you are lucky !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I use my browser. There's ads everywhere, even in the google main page.

Your computer (or at least, your browser) is infected with Adware (which I consider to be a special type of Malware).

So, uninstall your browser. Reinstall.

If that doesn't help, maybe some of the more common tools of spy- and adware removal will help, but I'll be honest with you:

I work with computers in all my jobs, and when one system shows such symptoms, it gets flattened, set up anew, and data is *very selectively* after *extensive anti-virus inspection* copied over to the new system. Trying to "fix" such systems is never giving you certainty it's not still infected, and I can't (neither for emotional, nor contractional reasons) accept the chance to work on a system that is infected with software that has the purpose of exfiltrating my user data (to show me targeted ads, or worse).

Answer (score 0):

If you dont care about the popups,new windows then you can follow below that works with firefox

1. Install Greasemonkey addon for firefox.
2. Create "New User Script"
3. Put below Javascript that will close any popups opened.

   window.open = function(){
           return;
       }

Comment: while this might work, this does not address the underlying issue that the browser is likely infected

Answer (score 0):

While I also consider this case to be adware infection, I would suggest taking a look at your add-ons and plugins for your browser. It may not be a "virus", but a legitimate software that inserts ads. I don't enjoy these but they do show up.

I've had an experience where i scanned and worked on for a week and a half trying to remove an adware virus without a restore/reset (browser or system) but i could not find any virus. I scoured my whole computer and couldn't find anything. as i decompiled some add-ons (to check code integrity and flat out satisfy my curiosity) i noticed that an add-on for music downloads (which had updated their terms) started inserting adds onto my browser. i simply uninstalled the add-on and solved my problem.

Comment: Some installers install "potentially unwanted programs" as a default option during updates, Adobe Flash Player is the most notable I know of.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian Shareware tends to do this often.I mentioned this only as a possibility and for future references that it may not be a worse case scenario.

 Imagine going through the trouble of doing a full system restore. Taking the time to backup and scan all of your information. Having a fresh start with everything. And once you get everything running again, you want to install that great little music streamer add-on and lo and behold, the ads are back.

Answer (score -1):

One solution can be ad-blockers.along with it you can use privacy badger,which doesn't allow the browser to record your browser information and history.Which stops the suggestion of different e-commerce and other website.

Comment: From the fact that this happened on Google's home page, we can understand that this is clearly not coming from the internet, but rather from Adware or some other Malware that has infected the OPs machine.